# Macro: Programmatically Remove Known Excel Passwords

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

Is there a means to remove a **KNOWN** password from an Excel file via a VBA macro? Web searches only return the method to crack unknown Excel passwords.

I've automated all other aspects of the data handling except downloading files from an FTP site and subsequently removing the password.

Comment: Password on a workbook, sheet or its VBA project?

Comment: The password on a workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to open the workbook specifying the passwords to open and modify, then saveas specifying an empty password for open and modify.  To avoid getting prompts when overwriting the existing file, you need to disable alerts.

e.g.

```
Sub OpenAndSaveWithoutPasswords()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="YOUR PATH AND FILENAME", Password:="OPEN PASSWORD", WriteResPassword:="MODIFY PASSWORD")
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="YOUR PATH AND FILENAME AGAIN", Password:="", WriteResPassword:=""

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Note: Workbooks.Open seems to require brackets, wb.SaveAs requires no brackets (don't ask me why).

Comment: This is great - thank you! Now I just need to learn how to loop through all the files in a folder and call different passwords from a list depending on the name of the file.

Comment: You'll need the Dir function

Answer (score 1):

Just resave the workbook without a password:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
```